# Connecting to a network with personal computer

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to limit connections to a companies network, via VPN, to certain computers?
For instance, is it possible to only allow certain authorized computers, and not any Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You want NAP Enforcement. There are NAP Enforcement components for 802.1x, DHCP, IPsec, VPN, etc. You can combine multiple NAP enforcement methods for increased security at the cost of increased complexity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770861.aspx

> Network Access Protection (NAP) enforcement for 802.1X port-based
>   network access control is deployed by using a server running Network
>   Policy Server (NPS) and an Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP)
>   host enforcement client component. With 802.1X port-based enforcement,
>   the NPS server instructs an 802.1X authenticating switch or an
>   802.1X-compliant wireless access point to place noncompliant 802.1X clients on a remediation network. The NPS server limits network access
>   by the client to the remediation network by applying IP filters or a
>   virtual LAN identifier to the connection. 802.1X enforcement provides
>   strong network restriction for all computers accessing the network by
>   using 802.1X-capable network access servers.

Here is some more specific information for the VPN enforcement component:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753622(v=WS.10).aspx

> Network Access Protection (NAP) enforcement for virtual private
>   networking (VPN) is deployed with a VPN enforcement server component
>   and a VPN enforcement client component. Using this enforcement method,
>   VPN servers can enforce health policy when client computers attempt to
>   connect to the network using a VPN connection. VPN enforcement
>   provides strong limited network access for all computers accessing the
>   network through a VPN connection.

Comment: Is there a hack around it, if I want to use my Mac in such a case, is it doable?

Comment: Well, as a general rule, *nothing* is "hack-proof," but depending on how exactly you design it, your deployment can be more or less "hackable." I mean, you'd have to figure out how to pretty much break certificate-based public key cryptography I think to really bypass it, so I would consider that pretty difficult to bypass.

Comment: ok, thx...if I have a soft token from a company to connect to their network, how do they know if I connect with a Windows or Mac?

Comment: That's kinda' irrelevant to this question. You can specify in your NAP enforcement policy what operating systems are and aren't allowed access. You could also combine this with, for instance, IPsec domain isolation such that nothing will talk to any device that isn't a member of the same AD domain.